# When the HMS Core SDK is updated to 5.0.4.300 or later, no pop-up is displayed to prompt users to install or update HMS Core (APK), and result code 90

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery

I updated the HMS Core SDK to 5.0.4.300 or later, but there was no pop-up asking me whether to install HMS Core (APK) or update it to the latest version. I checked the Logcat log file and found the following error message.

Error log:

HMSSDK_AppTouchTaskApiCall: Apptouch get the errorcode is 907135003
HMSSDK_AppUpdateClientImpl: 907135003: Connection Failed:update failed, because no activity incoming, can't pop update page(26)

Answer (score 1):

This problem may caused by missing metadata.

Pls kindly refer the instructions in the [official documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/integrating-sdk-0000001050035023#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050035023__section10411172415118?ha_source=hms1) to solve your problem.

[image]